# How do I use AUNetSend in GarageBand '09

Tags: garageband

I found this thread, about how to use AUNetSend waaaaay back in 2005- http://www.macjams.com/forum/viewtopic.php?forum=6;showtopic=28700

> Double click on any instrument track in GarageBand to open up "Track Info" screen. Choose an additional effect from the area below "Compressor" (it should say "None") Go all the way down to your Audio Unit Effects and you should see "AUNetSend" and "AUNetReceive". Depending on who is doing wha,t if you are the sender, the other person has to pick the "AUNetReceive" option. Now since I don't have Tiger, this is were I get lost and don't know how this actually works from here, but if 2 people would like to experiment and fill in the blanks I'm sure a lot of people would really appreciate it!

How do I do this today? Well... should I say how do I do this a month ago, since I haven't upgrade to iLife '11 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you’re using GarageBand ’09 (I think it’s the same in iLife ’11), you can still follow those very same instructions.

AUNetSend is an audio unit that uses Bonjour to send a stream of data in the format that you specify.

[image: AUNetSend]

You can then modify the properties of the “send”:

[image]

The “listening” side should be using AUNetReceive…

I haven’t really tried this since the age of dawn, but assuming both Macs are in the same network, it would be more or less straightforward.